# Lucene Indexing from Oracle:ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment

Tags: oracle, lucene, indexing, tablespace

I met a problem when using Lucene to build full-text index of the data from the Oracle 11g database, with the following information: 
"ora-01652 unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace temp, on MDSYS.SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S", line 608"

The total size of the dataset is about 1.5GB. After the problem occur, I followed some instructions online:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp01
TEMPFILE 'D:\oracle\oradata\temp01.dbf' SIZE 2048M AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;  

ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp01;
```

However, the problem is still there. The disk space is enough, though. Can anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `in tablespace temp` <> `in tablespace temp01`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tablespace is `MDSYS.SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S` in?  That's the tablespace to which space needs to be added.  Also, `MAXSIZE UNLIMITED` doesn't really mean unlimited; on most platforms, that means 32767 MB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is the reason because every time when the program throws out this database exception(ORA-01652), the size of the "dbf" file is roughly 33GB. So what should I supposed to do if the table space needs more than 33GB space?

Comment: Since the dataset itself is just 1.5GB, can anyone tell why the index building process by Lucene consumes that much of disk space?

Comment: @ChenXie: `Alter tablespace some_tablespace add datafile some_path_to_file size 1023m autoextend on next 1024m maxsize unlimited`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default temporary tablespace for the database doesn't modify the assigned value for existing users who explicitly had a temporary tablespace set. Check the user you're connecting as, in `dba_users`, and if it has a different temporary tablespace do `alter user <id> temporary tablespace temp01`.

You could also have increased the size of the existing temporary tablespace, by increasing the size of its tempfile, setting that to autoextend, or adding an additional tempfile. However, if this is a one-off task then creating a new large tablespace for it and dropping it afterwards may not be a bad idea.